# App crashing in every first launch from TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

My app got crashed in every first launch from Testflight. It runs perfectly well from debugger. After installing from Testflight, it shows splash screen for more than 20 seconds on first launch, then got crashed. But it works fine on second or third launch. No crash report generated in crashlytics and iTunes. 
I created ipa file and installed directly through devices option in xCode and it showing

```
failed to launch after 20.00s (launchIntent: foreground-interactive)
```

on first launch. It takes more than 20 seconds to launch in debugger too.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any solutions? Is very weird that this only happens on the very first launch after installing/updating from TestFlight (you can even uninstall the app and install it again, and this doesn't crash, so it's only once)

Comment: Can you share the didLaunchWithOptions method to see what's going on there?

Comment: @Nayana: Did you got a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the app is failing to launch in 20 seconds iOS is killing the process. No 3rd party SDK will be able to provide a crash report for this! You need to check the crash report on the actual device for more details.

You are doing something early in your apps code (most likely `applicationDidFinishLaunching`) which is taking too long and blocking the main thread.

Comment: I put a breakpoint in applicationDidFinishLaunching while debugging, but it was not fired during displaying splash screen for 20 seconds.

Comment: @Kerni: I got the same behaviour, when I added Intune sdk into our project. If I remove that sdk everything works perfectly fine. I can't guess whats going wrong while adding that sdk. Do you have any suggestions?